# how to change a CA certificate on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu

I would like to make changes to the data  supplied  when creating a Certification Authority
like email address.Is there a way to do it.I have  installed it but not yet used it to sign any certificates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, i think the only way is to regenerate the CA cert. If you've not signed with it yet, it makes it a lot easier to just regenerate it the right way first.